Smith normal form of a Jordan Matrix
I'm trying to find the Smith normal form of this $4\times4$ Jordan matrix:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda-a&1&0&0\\
0&\lambda-a&1&0\\
0&0&\lambda-a&1\\
0&0&0&\lambda-a
\end{pmatrix}
$$
I have to find both the Smith normal form and the invariant divisors. I know the final matrix is:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&(\lambda-a)^4
\end{pmatrix}
$$
but I cannot manage to do it. I asked the professor, and if I remember correctly a "staircase method" is useful for the solution.
Thanks in advance for the help.

start with the 2 by 2 upper left corner, the diagonal elements come out $1, (\lambda -a)^2 .$

Make two passes. First perform a series of column operations to eliminate the $\lambda-a$ entries from rows 1, 2, and 3. This comes at the expense of introducing new nonzero entries in row 4. But now the second pass is easy because by subtracting suitable multiples of rows 1, 2, and 3 from row 4, you can ensure that no column has more than one nonzero entry. Finally, you are free to reorder the columns.

Thanks, I did a bit of both, doing first a column operation between C1 and C2, then a row operation between R1 and R2, then continuing with column operation with C1 and C3, and row operation between R2 and R3, and so on, until I have all 1 diagonal except the last element to the fourth power.
